# Does wavelength-specific emissivity depend on temperature?

Tags: temperature, thermal-radiation, wavelength

The **wavelength-specific** emissivity $\epsilon_{\lambda}$ of a body is the ratio of the body's spectral radiance at the specific wavelength compared to that of the ideal blackbody. Does $\epsilon_{\lambda}$ depend on temperature?

If so, it would mean that an object with uniform $\epsilon_{\lambda}$ across all wavelength at one temperature might no longer have this property at another temperature. So am I right to say that the property of being a "grey body" is temperature dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it depends on temperature :
$$ 
\begin{align}
\varepsilon _{\lambda }&={\frac {M_{\mathrm {e} ,\lambda }}{M_{\mathrm {e} ,\lambda }^{\circ }}} 
\\&= {{\frac {\lambda ^{5} \left({e^{\frac {\mathrm {h} c}{\lambda \mathrm {k} T}}-1}\right)}{2\pi \mathrm {h} c^{2}}}} 
\cdot {\frac {\partial M_{\mathrm {e} }}{\partial \lambda }}
\\&={{\frac {\varepsilon \sigma \lambda ^{5} \left({e^{\frac {\mathrm {h} c}{\lambda \mathrm {k} T}}-1}\right)}{2\pi \mathrm {h} c^{2}}}} 
\cdot {\frac {\partial T^{4}  }{\partial \lambda }}
\end{align}
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is the emissivity coefficient of material surface and $\sigma$ is the Stefan–Boltzmann constant. So for being able to calculate wavelength-specific emissivity of body, you need to know it's temperature and it's temperature distribution law with respect to emitted wavelength (derivative part in equation).